# Как подключить css в nuxt js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Мой nuxt.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
        head: {
            meta: [
                {charset: 'utf-8'},
                {'http-equiv': 'X-UA-Compatible', content: 'IE=edge'}
            ],
            css: [
                'hover.css/css/hover-min.css',
                'bulma/css/bulma.css',
                 "HTML_design/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css",
                 "HTML_design/libs/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css",
                 "HTML_design/style.css",
                {src: "~/assets/css/style.css", lang: 'css'}
            ],
            build: {
                extractCSS: true
            }

        }
};
```

И мой package.json

```
{
  "name": "mynuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bulma": "^0.5.1",
    "hover.css": "^2.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0-rc4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Запускаю npm run build и npm run start, но css файлы не подключаются. Вот скриншот консоли[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как подключить css? Пробую так, как в доках, ничего не получается

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет о подключении стилей **глобально**, то в `nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    ...
  },
  css: [
    '~assets/css/main.css',
    { src: '~assets/sass/colors.scss', lang: 'scss' }
  ]
}
```

В продакшн версии, после сжатия и конкатенации стили будут находиться в файле `styles.css` в `<head>` страницы.

Другими словами, массив `css` размещается после объекта `head`, а не внутри него, как у Вас в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Версия nuxt должна быть меньше ^1.0.0-rc4. Я поставила 0.10.6 и все стало работать

Answer (score 1):

Также можно добавить специфичный файл со стилями в конкретный Page или Layout.
Вот пример условного page.vue:

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!-- Navbar content -->
  </nav>
</template>
    
<style>
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
</style>
```

В данном случае содержимое файла `bootstrap.min.css` будет заинлайнен на страницу `page`

p.s. Подключать бутстрап таким образом не рекомендую! Это просто для примера.